# I want to send a Postman POST request with an Array: members: ["william", "eric", "ryan"]

Tags: arrays, http, post, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

I want to send a post request with an array of strings in postman to my django-rest-framework backend api. I want to use POSTMAN raw, because I will use the code inside my flutter mobile app.

I have tried:

```
    {
    "name": "ChatRoom"
    "members": ["william", "eric", "ryan"],
    "messages": []
    }
```

Also Tried:

```
{
"name": "aassss",
"members": [
    {
        "username":"william"
    }
]
}
```

In Django this Is a ManyToManyField of User

Comment: In your first code example, comma is missing after "ChatRoom". Don't know whether it is a typo in question or it causes problem in your postman.

Comment: Also, please attach your postman screenshot. Maybe some information is missing.